# update/delete transformations on same target field

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a target table within an ETL mapping.

Pipe A, performs an update to fieldA. 
Pipe B I need to delete rows based on the value in fieldA (as well as a few other fields)

To perform the update, fieldA cannot be a PK. To perform the delete, fieldA is required to be a PK.

I'm trying to stay away from post-mapping SQL if I can so am seeking other options that may be available to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform update or delete, the actual physical table does not need to have Primary key, only the definition in Informatica should have the keys. I believe you can create two separate target definitions of the same table, and define different keys. You can then use those separate target definitions in the two pipelines.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I meant that the PK was defined on the target definition. Regardless, your answer is helpful! I found a separate work around (the cardinality of the target-defined PK was unique, so I could delete all records for the PK based on the condition of my measures), so it turned out to be a moot question for me. That said, I never thought to create two separate target definitions for the same table, good idea, maybe I'll use that for another issue in the future, thanks!